# ALSA - Retrieving audio buffer timestamps

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi, alsa, libasound

I have a simple C program that plays audio using the ALSA APIs and I wish to know the precise timing of the audio buffers.

I am attempting to retrieve the timestamps from the audio driver using ALSA's [snd_pcm_htimestamp](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga3946abd34178b3de60fd5329b71c189b) functionality, which returns two values - a timestamp and a frame count.

However, the timestamp returned from ALSA is unset (zero  values). The second returned variable, the "*number of available frames when timestamp was grabbed*", looks to be set correctly. Does anyone have an idea as to why the timestamps are seemingly unset?

I am configuring timestamps to be activated in my setup like so:

```
err = snd_pcm_sw_params_set_tstamp_mode(pcmHandle, swparams, SND_PCM_TSTAMP_ENABLE);
if (err < 0) {
    printf("Unable to set timestamp mode: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    return err;
}
```

And I verify that it has been set:

```
snd_pcm_tstamp_t timestampMode;
err = snd_pcm_sw_params_get_tstamp_mode(swparams, &timestampMode);
if (timestampMode != SND_PCM_TSTAMP_ENABLE)
{
    // error ...
}
```

Then in the program's main while loop, after I feed ALSA with samples using `snd_pcm_writei`, I attempt to obtain that buffer's timestamp like so:

```
snd_pcm_writei(pcmHandle, samples, frameCount);

snd_htimestamp_t ts;
snd_pcm_uframes_t avail;
err = snd_pcm_htimestamp(pcmHandle, &avail, &ts);
if (err < 0)
{
    printf("Unable to get timestamp: %s\n", snd_strerror(err));
    return err;
}
printf("avail: %d\n", avail);
printf("%lld.%.9ld", (long long)ts.tv_sec, ts.tv_nsec);
```

However, whilst `avail` seems to be set, `ts` is always 0.000000000.

I am on a Raspberry Pi running Raspbian with an ADA1475 audio interface.

Thanks in advance,
Andy

Comment: High-resolution timestamps require hardware support; see `snd_pcm_hw_params_supports_audio_wallclock_ts`/`snd_pcm_hw_params_supports_audio_ts_type`.

Comment: Ah… thanks! snd_pcm_hw_params_supports_audio_wallclock_t returns 0 on my hardware so that explains my issue (strangely snd_pcm_hw_par‌​ams_supports_audio_t‌​s_type doesn't seem to be present in my libasound library).

Answer (score 1):

The change to swparams must be applied to the PCM interface with `snd_pcm_sw_params()`.

```
/* Allocate a temporary swparams struct */
snd_pcm_sw_params_t *swparams;
snd_pcm_sw_params_alloca(&swparams);

/* Retrieve current SW parameters. */
snd_pcm_sw_params_current(pcmHandle, swparams);

/* Change software parameters. */
snd_pcm_sw_params_get_tstamp_mode(swparams, SND_PCM_TSTAMP_ENABLE);
snd_pcm_sw_params_set_tstamp_type(pcmHandle, swparams, SND_PCM_TSTAMP_TYPE_GETTIMEOFDAY);

/* Apply updated software parameters to PCM interface. */
snd_pcm_sw_params(pcmHandle, swparams);  // <-- Change takes effect here.
```

ALSA allows [software parameters](https://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m___s_w___params.html) to be changed at any time, even while the stream is running.